# Узнать букву последней и предпоследней колонки в Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Имеется таблица в Excel, где:

- A - код товара
- B - Название товара
- C - Магазины где есть этот товар
- Цена товара
- Бонусы, которые получит покупатель

Магазинов может быть много, то есть Цена и Бонусы находятся постоянно в разных колоннах, но они всегда в конце таблицы:

[image: Таблица excel]

Как средствами библиотеки openpyxl получить букву последней и предпоследней колонок?

Comment: Для того, чтобы найти предпоследнюю ячейку, требуется из ws.max_column вычесть 1, и получится предпоследняя ячейка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter()](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/utils/cell.html?highlight=get_column_letter) и атрибутом [worksheet.max_column](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=max_column#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.max_column):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


fn = r"C:\temp\desc.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(fn)
ws = wb.active
last_column_letter = get_column_letter(ws.max_column)

print(f"Last column: [{last_column_letter}]")
print(f"Last but one column: [{get_column_letter(ws.max_column-1)}]")
```

---

результат:

```
Last column: [L]
Last but one column: [K]
```